# Json сериализация списка

Tags: c#, json, list, serializable

Создал класс однонаправленного связного списка

```
public class List<T>
    where T : class, IComparable<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Максимально допустимое количество элементво в хранилище
    /// </summary>
    private const int size = 10;

    /// <summary>
    /// Хранилище элементов
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly Element[] storage;

    /*методы для работы с элементами*/

    public void Upload()
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling  = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            NullValueHandling           = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            Formatting                  = Formatting.Indented
        };

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
            writer.WriteLine(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, settings));
    }

    protected class Element : BaseElement<T, int>
    { }
}

/// <summary>
/// Базовый класс для элементов структур данных
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Тип данных информационной части</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="N">Тип данных ссылки</typeparam>
public class BaseElement<T, N>
    where T : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Информационная часть элемента структуры данных
    /// </summary>
    public T Inf { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ссылка на следующий элемент
    /// </summary>
    public N Next { get; set; }
}
```

Возникла проблема при сериализации созданного  заполненного экземпляра. В файл записывается только значение одного из свойств(имеющее только get-ер). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать сериализацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию метод `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` сериализует все **открытые** экземплярные поля и свойства класса, именно по этой причине ваше поле `storage`, имеющее модификатор доступа `protected` не попадает в результирующий json-файл.

Это поведение сериализатора Json.NET можно изменить, установив для вашего класса атрибут

```
 [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]
```

Теперь кроме public полей и свойств будут сериализованы все **non-public** (protected, internal, ...) поля и свойства.

Кстати, исключить ненужные для сериализации члены класса можно с помощью атрибутов `[JsonIgnore]` или `[NonSerialized]` (только для полей).

Comment: А как после этого его корректного десериализовать?

Comment: @EgoPingvina https://pastebin.com/HmFdHjr0

Comment: Вроде делал уже так, странно, попробовал - заработало, спасибо.